# Cancel a DataAdapter.Fill when it is waiting for query result

Tags: c#, sql, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

As the title suggest, I will like to have a functionality that cancel a DataAdapter.Fill() for certain reason.

Most of the solutions provided is to assign an event to dataTable.RowChanged that will throw an exception whenever I need to cancel DataAdapter.Fill. But this will only works when DataAdapter is already populating the dataTable. What if dataAdapter is still waiting for the query result? Is there a way to cancel the query instead of waiting for the query result to comeback and trigger the exception in dt.RowChanged.

Comment: Try this https://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/cancelling-dataadapter-fill-method-on-the-fly-by-throwing-an-error/

Comment: I suggest you invoke the Fill call within an async Task, which allows you to cancel the task when needed.

Comment: @dotnetkid As i mentioned in my question, I am fully aware of the method of triggering a exception through RowChanged Event, but that require the dataAdapter to start populating the dataTable before anything can happen. I need something to cancel the Fill() when it is waiting for the query result.

Comment: @sudheeshix I dont really get what you mean by that, can you please elaborate more? An example perhaps? Thank you